# PowerShell verify URL's SSL Certificate expiration date through PROXY

Tags: .net, powershell, ssl, url, proxy

I am trying to build a script to extract SSL Certificate Expire Date for selected URLs. Following tutorial (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-website-ssl-certificate-validity-dates-with-powershell) I managed to properly find expiration date of certificates inside domain.

I need to modify the script to be able to access URLs through a proxy, but as I lack experience with .NET could anyone please modify the script to work ?

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { $true }
$url = "https://myserver.domain/HealthCheck"

         #Line to Modify
$req = [Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($url)


$req.GetResponse()  #Running this will populate certificate property
$req.ServicePoint.Certificate
    $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.Issuer
    $req.ServicePoint.Certificate.Subject
$req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetEffectiveDateString()
$req.ServicePoint.Certificate.GetExpirationDateString()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Check first if your proxy replaces real certificate with it's own (proxy) certificate. Look at certificate chain. If so, you will not be able to get real certificate through proxy.

Comment: Hi @filimonic , the proxy doesn't replace the certificates.